# How do I prepare the test set shape for the model.evaluate with keras and tensorflow?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, syntax-error, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to run a simple example with a NN using the MNIST dataset provided by tensorflow itself, running on Google Colab. I want to get the raw data and mount by myself the structure that has the data. I'm able to train the NN, but when I try to predict one example from the test set, I get the error

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_input to have shape (784,) but got array with shape (1,).
```

Could somebody help me with this issue? I'm pretty new to Python and Keras/TensorFlow.

When I run

```py
print(inp.shape)
```

I get (784,) and not the (1,) as the error says.

I have also tried to evaluate the test set using

```py
test_loss, test_accuracy = model.evaluate(test_input.T)
```

, but I also get the error

```
ValueError: Arguments and signature arguments do not match: 25 27.
```

The source code is the following:

```py
# Importing stuff
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math
import time
import keras

tf.enable_eager_execution()

# Functions
def normalize(images, labels):
  images = tf.cast(images, tf.float32)
  images /= 255
  return images, labels

# Getting dataset
ds, meta = tfds.load('fashion_mnist', as_supervised=True, with_info=True)

test_ds, train_ds = ds['test'], ds['train']

# Preprocess the data
train_ds =  train_ds.map(normalize)
test_ds  =  test_ds.map(normalize)

num_train_examples = meta.splits['train'].num_examples
num_test_examples = meta.splits['test'].num_examples

# Making the train set
train_input = np.empty(shape=(784, num_train_examples))
train_label = np.empty(shape=(1, num_train_examples))

i = 0
for image, label in train_ds:
  image = image.numpy().reshape((784, 1))
  train_input[:, i] = image.ravel()
  label = label.numpy().reshape(1)
  train_label[:, i] = label
  i = i + 1;

# Making the test set
test_input = np.empty(shape=(784, num_test_examples))
test_label = np.empty(shape=(1, num_test_examples))

i = 0
for image, label in test_ds:
  image = image.numpy().reshape((784, 1))
  test_input[:, i] = image.ravel()
  label = label.numpy().reshape(1)
  test_label[:, i] = label
  i = i + 1;

# Network
input_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=784, input_shape=[784])
h1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu)
output_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)

model = tf.keras.Sequential([input_layer, h1, output_layer])

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(train_input.T, train_label.T, epochs=3, steps_per_epoch=100, batch_size=1)

test_loss, test_accuracy = model.evaluate(test_input.T)

inp = test_input[:, 0].T
res = model.predict(inp)
```

Answer (score 0):

All the API functions expect an input shape containing the batch size first. In your case, you're trying to feed only 1 example and thus no batch size is given. You just need to specify your batch size as 1 by reshaping the data.

Using numpy:

```
res = model.predict(np.reshape(inp, len(inp))
```

The argument to the `predict` method now receives the array with shape `(1, 784)` in your case, specifying the batch size as 1.

When you give the function more examples to evaluate by stacking them on top of one another, the batch size is implicitly given by the shape of the array, so no further transformation is necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! I tried to run the command as you said, but I still got "ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_input to have shape (784,) but got array with shape (1,)".